# VS2013.4 CTP2 TypeScript version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

What version of TypeScript comes with VS2013.4 CTP2? And is there some way I can find out without having to install the update?

Answer (score 0):

I should still be 1.0.x (probably 1.0.3) as the 1.1 release isn't yet available (and is a major compiler rewrite that will give performance gains).

Of course, if someone has already downloaded it, they will be able to confirm this or supply a corrected answer.

Comment: from others I've heard 1.0.3